# Simple dynamics im really confused

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, mass, free-body-diagram, weight, scales

So my question is a little dumb: if an object on a scale has a weight that points downwards and the scale exerts normal force on the object upwards, cancelling the forces acted on the object then what does the scale read? Also the action-reaction pair to the normal force is supposed to be the force that the object act on the scale, is this what the scale reads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reading on the scale or spring balance shows the force that the spring balance exerts on the object. If the object is not accelerating then we can say that the net force on the object is zero, so the force exerted on the object by the spring balance is equal in magnitude to the weight of the object.

However, if the object is accelerating then the force exerted on the object by the spring balance may be greater than or less than the object's weight. If we put the spring balance and the object in a lift that is accelerating upwards, then the reading on the spring balance will be greater than the object's weight, since it has to exert a greater force on the object in order to accelerate it.

On the other hand, if we tie the object to the spring balance and throw both off a cliff then on the way down the reading on the spring balance will be zero, since it is not exerting any force on the object.

Answer (score 0):

You have got the right idea: an idealized scale is a machine that displays the normal force supplied to the objects with which it is in contact.

Here is a model of how to make a scale: Put a ruler behind a spring of known spring constant $k$ (units: Newtons/meter). When an object exerts a force on the spring the spring will be compressed some number of meters $x$. Multiply $x$ by $k$ to figure out the force that the spring applies. In the FBD of the object we would refer to "the force that the spring applies" as the "normal force on the object," as justified by Newton's Third Law.